# csv, xml, etc import in a restful way

Tags: import, restful-architecture

We are in the proces of adding our data import functionality to our RESTful interface.

We are trying to come up with a RESTful way to handle this proces.

From a user perspective we have the following proces:
(1) The user uploads a file (2) the user selects some configuration options that control how the data is entered into the system and the system presents a preview of the result (the user can change the settings untill satisfied) (3) once the user confirms everything is correct the  import is executed. This results in new elements being created in the /participants resource.

Currently we upload the data to a /imports resource on step 1. Everytime the user changes the import configuration we save the new configuration to the resource and get back a new preview. We have a differenco of opinion about what the "go ahead and process the input" action should look like and whether it should be posted to the /import or /participants resource.

We are not completely happy with the amount of actions we need to get this going but we cant change the user scenario for functional reasons.

What would be the most restful way of dealing with the "go ahead and process the import" stage (it feels SOAP'y) or how can we change this if necessary?

Answer (score 1):

You uploaded an "import" so you should "process" that import.

Perhaps something like:

`POST /import/<id>/process`

To this, you would return a status code of `202 Accepted` since you'll be actually creating something else